# Deleting first node of a linear linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I came across the following code for deleting the first node of a linked list:

```
Node* removeFirstNode(struct Node* head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
  
    // Move the head pointer to the next node
    Node* temp = head;
    head = head->next;
  
    delete temp;
  
    return head;
}
```

Can someone explain me:

1. The significance of using the temp variable i.e. could we use this code without temp variable

2.What does the assignment head=head->next do?

3. What is the relation between head and temp i.e. is temp a pointer to head?
4. Is head also a pointer to the first node of a linked list?
5. If answer to third and fourth part both is yes, then doesn't temp become a double pointer (pointer to a pointer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `temp` pointer is needed because the memory for the first node in the linked list needs to be freed using `delete` after `head` is reassigned. This prevents a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) when calling the function.
2. The assignment `head = head->next` moves the beginning of the linked list to the second node, before the first node is deleted.
3. The assignment `Node *temp = head` makes `temp` point to the same address as `head`, but after `head` is reassigned (see point 2) the pointers don't point to the same address anymore.
4. Yes, `head` is the pointer to the beginning of the linked list.
5. No `temp` is never of type `Node **`, but `head` is reassigned (see point 3).

Comment: Well answered but I couldn't get the fifth part i.e. why temp is never of type "Node **"

Comment: Also, is it possible to deallocate memory for the head without using temp pointer?

Comment: @proglove Why should `temp` be of type `Node **`? Please explain your rationale for it being a double-pointer. Then it's easier for me to address the reason, why it isn't of type `Node **`.

Comment: @proglove And concerning your second comment. I don't think there is an easy way to deallocate the memory of the first node without `temp`, but I will let you know, should I stumble upon an easier way in the future.

Comment: Because temp points to head and head points to the first element of linked list, hence according to me it should be a double pointer.

Comment: @proglove `temp` doesn't point to `head`. After the assignment `Node *temp = head` the pointer `temp` points to the same address as `head`, so after the assignment both pointers point to the same data structure.